# c# when pressing a button add totals together

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When i press "buttonTotal" i need it to add fuel prices together. I have lblDailyPrice, lblTotalLitresEntered and i have 3 buttons "unleaded"; "Diesel"; "Premium"... any help as to how i can achieve this?

```
private void btnTotal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            if(btnUnleaded_Click)
            {

            }
            else if (btnDiesel_Click)
            {

            }
            else if (btnPremium_Click)
            {

            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }
}
```

Comment: Example code seems incomplete and/or the question is a little too vague. Where do you get the values to add? I'm confused as to how the sample code relates to the question. Please give more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise making the "unleaded", "Diesel", "Premium" options RadioButtons instead of Buttons and bind them under a container like Panel. So, when the user presses the "buttonTotal" the program will check which RadioButton is checked and then calculate the corresponding value.

```
private void btnTotal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        double totalPrice = 0;
        if(unleadedRadioButton.Checked)
        {
             totalPrice = lblDailyPrice * lblTotalLitresEntered * unleadedValue;
        }
        else if (dieselRadioButton.Checked)
        {
             totalPrice = lblDailyPrice * lblTotalLitresEntered * dieselValue;
        }
        else if (premiumRadioButton.Checked)
        {
             totalPrice = lblDailyPrice * lblTotalLitresEntered * premiumValue;
        }
}
```

Comment: i see where you're coming from but I'm going to have a different approach this by using a different method all together

Answer (score -3):

I'm assuming your using Windows Forms. I have linked relevant documentation on how to accomplish this task. With just a tiny bit of reading, it should be easy. Good luck and welcome to StackOverflow!.

1. [Get the prices from the labels.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0cs4xb3d(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. [Convert those strings into a number type with a decimal.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397679.aspx)

Then just do the math on the resulting variables.

Example:

```
var total = Convert.ToDecimal(lblDailyPrice.Text) * Convert.ToDecimal(lblTotalLitresEntered.Text);
```